# Problem with predicates with inner object references in RealmSwift query

Tags: ios, realm, swift4

I have a Report class such as:

```
class Report: Object{

   @objc dynamic var id : String? = nil
   @objc dynamic var studentProfileId : String? = nil
   @objc dynamic var createdAt : String? = nil
   @objc dynamic var updatedAt : String? = nil
   @objc dynamic var type : String? = nil
   @objc dynamic var status : String? = nil
   @objc dynamic var assessment : AssessmentLocal? = nil
   var avgScore = RealmOptional<Double>(0)
}
```

Report class has a assessment variable for AssessmentLocal class.

```
class AssessmentLocal: Object{

   @objc dynamic var id : String?
   @objc dynamic var status : String?
   @objc dynamic var type : String?
   @objc dynamic var code : String?
   @objc dynamic var cycle = 0
   var year = RealmOptional<Int>(0)
   @objc dynamic var startDate : String?
   @objc dynamic var grade : String?
}
```

I am trying to query using the following predicate:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "studentProfileId = %@ AND assessment.year = %@ AND assessment.cycle >= %@", report.studentProfileId!, String((report.assessment?.year.value)!), String((report.assessment?.cycle)!))

let reports = getDatabase().objects(Report.self).filter(predicate).sorted(byKeyPath: "assessment.cycle")
```

Whenever, i am trying to get saved reports, i am getting a crash.

> "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException".

I am unable to figure this out.

Comment: "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" does not tell you much. What does it say after or before that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurred probably because you have different types from what Realm expects.

`assessment.cycle` and `assessment.year` are integers, so you shouldn't use `%@` for their placeholders. `%@` is for strings. You should use `%i` for integers.

You should also remove the conversion to strings in the parameters.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "studentProfileId = %@ AND assessment.year = %i AND assessment.cycle >= %i", 
                            report.studentProfileId!, 
                            report.assessment?.year.value!, 
                            report.assessment?.cycle!
                            )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do also like this.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "studentProfileId = %@ AND assessment.year = \(report.assessment?.year.value!) AND assessment.cycle >= \(report.assessment?.cycle!)", report.studentProfileId!)
```